# Class Inheritance/Override

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class, inheritance, overriding

I have a general class.
And I want to create another class, but with less (or more) specific information.

So I convert from one class to another.

How I can build a dynamic inheritance "OtherClass"?

How  I can overwrite when creating a new class?

```
public class NewClass: Atom
{
 ...
}
public class OtherNewClass
    {
        // Elements

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "NewNew")]
        public string newnew { get; set; }
}
```

My code:

```
public class Atom
{
    [XmlType(TypeName = "feed", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
    public class Feed
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "updated")]
        public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "link")]
        public Link Link { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "entry")]
        public List<Entry> Entries { get; set; }

        public Feed()
        {
            Entries = new List<Entry>();
        }
    }

    public class Entry : OtherClass
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "updated")]
        public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "link")]
        public List<Link> Link { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "category")]
        public Category Category { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "author")]
        public Author Author { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "content")]
        public string Content { get; set; }           [

    }

    [XmlType(TypeName="otherclass", Namespace ="spec/1.0/")]
    public class OtherClass
    {
        // Elements

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "code")]
        public string code { get; set; }
}
```

One tip that you can give me to do this.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @RenéVogt From my general class (Atom) create other classes where perhaps only Entry / OtherClass will be different. Override ?